# hamburger menu is unstable in mobile screen using Bootstrap 5

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

Desktop screen is good but facing 2 issues with mobile screen:

JSFiddle Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/uyvdqL9s/

1. When I'm on the mobile screen, the hamburger menu appears in the middle instead of the right along with the search button. It should be like this:

[image]

2. When I click on the Hamburger menu, the `Search` button disappears and shows up inside the collapsible menu. I want this to remain where it is as shown below:
   [image]

What am I doing wrong? Please help. I've been struggling with this for days now!

Comment: Please see [ask]. You're expected to show your code here. You can easily create a demo with the editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`navbar` class in bootstrap use `justify-content: space-between;` property

```
 /* Distribute items evenly
 The first item is flush with the start,
 the last is flush with the end */
```

what you should do is put `navigation button` and `search button` inside a `division` so

select it :

```
     <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" 
     data-bs-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria- 
     expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
     <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
     </button>
```

and replace it with this :

```
<div class="d-flex gap-2">

     <!--  navigation button -->
     <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" 
     data-bs-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria- 
     expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
     <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
     </button>

     <!--  search division -->
     <div class="search">
        <button data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" href="#demo">S</button>
     </div>

</div>
```

then delete `old search div`

https://jsfiddle.net/kpfx89av/

**Edit update** : https://jsfiddle.net/yqhvm5pk/15/

Comment: Thanks but that messes up the desktop view!

Comment: @elaine
I updated the answer in the new FIDDLE you can find the solution.

Unfortunately, bootstrap does not support the Responsive-Position currency. Should. The solution is to define two separate search buttons. I suggest you go toward the use of Tailwindcss

Comment: Thanks. I'll look it up on Tailwindcss.